# Laravel showing relationship as null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a simple eloquent relationship to my user model called "courses", which I recently renamed from "products" (that may be relevant).

```
    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
    }
```

The courses model relates to the "courses" table, which has an "expert_id" column.

When I try to call $expert->courses, I get a null result.

When I rename it the relationship back to "products" or any other arbitrary value - with no other changes - the relationship returns the expected results.

I've tried clearing all the caches, dumping composer autoload, and re-running migrations...

Any thoughts?

Renaming the relationship on the user model - works

php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize

None of those fix the issue if it's named "courses"

Comment: Can you give more explanation with all the relation and and model?

Comment: What other information would be helpful?

Comment: Did you try php artisan optimize:clear?

Comment: For your information, if `expert_id` is a foreign key of users id (User model) then, you need to add `expert_id` to your relationship method as well `$this->hasMany(Course::class, 'expert_id');`

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen I hadn't tried that, but just did with the same results.